# Civievent Template

Tags: civievent

I'm working on determining what is causing the following behavior and trying to determine if it's a bug or user error.

I have an event template set up for a recurring monthly event that we host.

I am attempting to set up a new event. During the initial set-up, I select the template that I would like to use for the new event. After setting the event date, etc, I hit the "Continue" button. Upon doing so, instead of creating a new event based on that template, a new template is created.  Therefor there is no event created and a duplicate template is created.

I found the same behavior on the WP demo site and the Joomla site was not working in order for me to test it (I am using Joomla).

This behavior did not occur previously but I am not sure which version it started. I am currently using 5.9.0 for Joomla.

Comment: This has been identified as a bug. you can view the details and progress for fixing it at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/653.

Comment: Ben, Thank You..I figured that was the case. Thanks for the info and I'll keep an eye on the progress

Answer (score 2):

Taylor,

This is a regression bug and is logged [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/653). I have submitted a [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13478) for it which should get merge this week and will be available in next release. In meantime can you please QA if it fixes the bug by applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13478.patch)?

Please post your QA results on [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13478) so that it will help to speed up the process in getting the PR merged ASAP.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Has this been fixed? Is there a patch that is ready to apply?

Comment: pradeep said he did a fix with a link so you can follow that to see if it is merged or not

Comment: i see it saying "merged 1 commit into civicrm:5.10" so yes is fixed in 5.10.x